# Remove Special Characters From Text With NLP Analysis

Tags: nlp

I have some texts like `"google+", "facebook+", ".facebook", "H&M", "google "...`

Here, I want to create a keyword filtering and I want to to remove meaningless special characters from string.

Example:

```
"google+" => "google+" => meaningful because there is a service like "Google+"
"H&M" => "H&M" => meaningful because there is a service like "H&M"
"facebook+" => "facebook" => "+" in this text is meaningless then remove it.
".facebook" => "facebook" => "." in this text is meaningless then remove it.
"google " => "google" => Emoji in this text is meaningless then remove it.
```

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do with an algorithm because meaningful and meaningless are considered subjective without any sort of reference.

Your best bet is to find one or multiple datasets somewhere that contain the types of tags you're referring to. Then you can check whether or not the dataset contains the full string or not. If the datasets do not contain them, simply start stripping the special characters and check again.

One dataset you could potentially use is: https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stacklite

You could also make assumptions about the tags and always remove trailing special characters.

```py
words = ["google+", "H&M", "facebook+", ".facebook", "google "]
keywords = [word.strip('$?^_.+!@#:() ') for word in words]

Output: ['google', 'H&M', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google']
```

Potentially you could combine both solutions to also get google+.